# Filled out form fields are left blank when using /includepdf

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I have included a PDF file in my document using

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{pdf/document_to_include.pdf}
```

This works fine, except document.pdf has form fields which are filled out (and the document has been saved) and those are left blank in my output PDF.

(When I open document_to_include.pdf in any PDf viewer, the form fields are filled out.)

Any Chance of having them rendered in the output PDF?

Comment: Some workarounds are mentioned here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194958/includepdf-combined-pdf-highlights-missing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used Mac OS's print->save-as-pdf function to render it again.

While the document now beeing no longer a editable PDF-form, the filled out fields are now included and rendered correctly.

Still wondering if you could include PDF Forms and having filled out fields rendered...