# Fill out forms of included pdf

Tags: pdfpages, forms, fill

A minimalistic example would be:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[]{fillable.pdf}
% fill the forms ...
\end{document}
```

Where `filable.pdf` has at least one text form, which can be filled in using a PDF viewer/editor.

Is there a way to fill in the text form with LaTeX?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in LaTeX? There are scriptable PDF tools that can handle this.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang I currently work with [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) and using external tools would be inconvenient, but probably better than filling everything out manually. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I didn't manage to fill out forms with LaTeX yet, but I was able to achieve what I wanted using the `overpic` package. One can write on a PDF file like on an image as described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20802/161492).

Comment: Yes, that's an option.

Comment: Also, it appears Overleaf allows compiling with the `--shell-escape` option, so you might be able to drive a script using `pdftk` to fill in the form fields.

Comment: See also [pdf - Filled out form fields are left blank when using /includepdf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63600/filled-out-form-fields-are-left-blank-when-using-includepdf), but not exactly the same question.