# Insert PDF form with values

Tags: pdfpages, include, forms

I would like to include a filled PDF form in my document. My current workflow is as follows:

- Fill the form using Adobe Acrobat
- Print to PDF (to make the editing functionality go away and "bake" the values into the PDF)
- Include the printed PDF using `\includepdf`

Is there a way I can just include an unfilled form and use a command to fill it? That way I could get rid of all of those steps and just have the form values inside my TEX file.

Comment: Not the same thing, but in any case if you know the exact same coordinate of the fields on the PDF you can just use [tikz pgf - How can/should I include annotated images? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/how-can-should-i-include-annotated-images) .  (the output should look the same)

Comment: See also [pdf - Filled out form fields are left blank when using /includepdf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63600/filled-out-form-fields-are-left-blank-when-using-includepdf) and linked questions

Comment: Actually same question as [pdfpages - Fill out forms of included pdf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541887/fill-out-forms-of-included-pdf) , there's a similar solution mentioned there using `overpic`